# Dynamic table with 2 columns based on array length

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I've got an array with dynamic length for example :

`(2) [" Corn starch 33.02%", " sugar 22.21%"]`

second time it might be different size

`(3) [" Corn starch 33.02%", " sugar 22.21%", " sea salt 20.27% ]"`

Now I have table which I can fill the data from array, but only if array length matchs table row.

```
<div class="tab-pane" id="adv">
  <div class="section-title">
    <div class="row content">
      <br /><br />

      <div id="elo" class="col-lg-6 pt-6 pt-lg-2">
        <div id="stylized" class="myform">
          <form id="form" name="form" method="post" action="index.html">
            <div class="column" name="details" id="co">
              <label>ING name: </label>
              <input
                type="text"
                name="ing1"
                id="name1"
                class="form-control input-md"
              />
              <input
                type="text"
                name="ing2"
                id="name2"
                class="form-control input-md"
              />
              <input
                type="text"
                name="ing3"
                id="name3"
                class="form-control input-md"
              />
              <input
                type="text"
                name="ing4"
                id="name4"
                class="form-control input-md"
              />
              <input
                type="text"
                name="ing5"
                id="name5"
                class="form-control input-md"
              />
              <input
                type="text"
                name="ing6"
                id="name6"
                class="form-control input-md"
              />
              <input
                type="text"
                name="ing7"
                id="name7"
                class="form-control input-md"
              />
              <input
                type="text"
                name="ing8"
                id="name8"
                class="form-control input-md"
              />
              <input
                type="text"
                name="ing9"
                id="name9"
                class="form-control input-md"
              />
              <input
                type="text"
                name="ing10"
                id="name10"
                class="form-control input-md"
              />
              <input
                type="text"
                name="ing11"
                id="name11"
                class="form-control input-md"
              />
              <input
                type="text"
                name="ing12"
                id="name12"
                class="form-control input-md"
              />
              <input
                type="text"
                name="ing13"
                id="name13"
                class="form-control input-md"
              />
            </div>
            <div class="column">
              <label>Total %: </label>
              <input
                type="text"
                name="value1"
                id="value1"
                class="form-control input-md"
              />
              <input
                type="text"
                name="value2"
                id="value2"
                class="form-control input-md"
              />
              <input
                type="text"
                name="value3"
                id="value3"
                class="form-control input-md"
              />
              <input
                type="text"
                name="value4"
                id="value4"
                class="form-control input-md"
              />
              <input
                type="text"
                name="value5"
                id="value5"
                class="form-control input-md"
              />
              <input
                type="text"
                name="value6"
                id="value6"
                class="form-control input-md"
              />
              <input
                type="text"
                name="value7"
                id="value7"
                class="form-control input-md"
              />
              <input
                type="text"
                name="value8"
                id="value8"
                class="form-control input-md"
              />
              <input
                type="text"
                name="value9"
                id="value9"
                class="form-control input-md"
              />
              <input
                type="text"
                name="value10"
                id="value10"
                class="form-control input-md"
              />
              <input
                type="text"
                name="value11"
                id="value11"
                class="form-control input-md"
              />
              <input
                type="text"
                name="value12"
                id="value12"
                class="form-control input-md"
              />
              <input
                type="text"
                name="value13"
                id="value13"
                class="form-control input-md"
              />
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

now I can question is it possible to build table based on array length with dynamic ID for every single input.

What I am expecting as a output if for example my array length is 10, then create table with 10 rows where i can fill data from array

Comment: Yes - It is possible to build the HTML table based upon the array and yes you could create a unique id for each element - but you do not need ID attributes generally ~ the `name` is more important.

Comment: Could You share with me example for 1 row or something that i would extend it to my needs or something, i dont know how to start it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With basic JavaScript:

```js
const data = ['Corn starch 33.02%', 'sugar 22.21%', 'sea salt 20.27'];

// Storing the table element
const tableElement = document.querySelector('#myTable');

// Generated HTML
let generated = '';

// Iterate over the list
for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  let dat = data[i];
  
   // Generating HTML with data
   generated += `
   <tr>
    <td>
      <input 
        type="text"
        name="value${i+1}" 
        value="${dat}" 
        class="form-control input-md"
       />
     </td>
   </tr>`
}

// Appending it to the <table> element
tableElement.innerHTML = generated;
```

```html
<form method='post' name='form'>
  <table id="myTable">
  </table>
</form>
```

This is just an "easy" way, the correct one is to use DOM which is more complex.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly then a simple `foreach` loop to iterate through the array combined with some basic HTML generation should suffice. The following will add a new row for every item in the array with an input element named like `value1`...`value100` etc

```
<form method='post' name='form'>
    <table>
    <?php
    
        $arr=array(
            'Corn starch 33.02%',
            'sugar 22.21%',
            'sea salt 20.27'
        );
        foreach( $arr as $i => $item ){
            printf('<tr><td><input type="text" name="value%d" value="%s" class="form-control input-md" /></td></tr>',($i+1),$item);
        }

    ?>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: its php , i dont know how to use it , ill try in javascript

Comment: What is the problem? A basic array of arbitrary length ( as mentioned ) is used as the source as shown above. A `foreach` loop allows you to process each entry in the array and then use basic PHP functions to `print` the HTML to screen